# Dell UltraSharp U2410 Monitor emitting burning smell

Tags: display, hardware-failure

About a month ago my approximately nine year old [Dell UltraSharp U2410](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/cty/ultrasharp-u2410-61-cm-24-widescreen-monitor/spd/dell-u2410) started emitting a burning smell. I live on a very tight fixed income, so I can't afford to replace this monitor.

It doesn't smell like dust burning. It smells more like electrical components are burning/melting. Is this a common problem with this and similar monitors? Will the monitor catch fire? Is there an inexpensive fix?

I have the ability to disassemble the monitor and replace capacitors, resistors, etc., but I am concerned that a proprietary component might be the problem and, although I have searched the internet, I have not been able to find a place to purchase repair parts for the U2410.

Any help with any of my issues would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I have a U2407 I still use to a certain extent that's three years older than yours.  They're very well built.  I'd start by taking the back cover off and look for anything obvious.  They do get quite hot, and if you smell the top exhaust area it will have that really hot electronics smell normally.

It could be as simple as blowing the dust off a heatsink.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the skill and tools, you've got nothing to lose by looking.  You will either spot a component that you can replace or you won't.  And JP Duffy's advice of doing a prophylactic cleaning can't hurt; there's a chance it could save you from creating new damage unintentionally.

I would be tempted to wait on any actual repair, though.  If something is in the process of releasing its magic smoke, it will be easier to spot once it actually fails, and its failure isn't likely to cause a cascade of other failed parts.  There also isn't a realistic chance of a failed part causing a fire.  A tiny bit of melting plastic can create stink out of proportion to its scope.  There is also some risk that your actions could damage something.  Once the monitor is no longer working, there's no downside.

If you see a charred or melted part, you'll know at least one part that failed.  But board-level repairs beyond that really benefit from service manuals.  You are likely to see a label, "No user-serviceable parts inside", which is a good indication that there isn't much you can do without a service manual and access to proprietary parts.

Yes, there's a possibility that a proprietary part is failing.  Just don't remove anything until you verify that a replacement is available to you.

Just for perspective, you can replace the monitor with a comparable one for the ballpark of $200 (e.g., [Dell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005JN9310), [Acer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00QS0B9ZG)).  And it will be new and come with a warranty.  It probably won't be cost effective to have yours commercially repaired.  The cost will be a substantial portion of buying a new one, it would likely involve swapping a board for a refurbished one with a short warranty, and you would still have an old monitor with other aging components.

Also keep in mind that if it dies and you can't fix it, and you can't afford to replace it, you still have options.  You may be able to find a used monitor at a very low price.  You might be able to get by with a lesser monitor.  New, smaller monitors with less resolution are available under $70.

Realistically, though, all electronics eventually die.  Given your monitor's age and burning aroma, it would be smart to start planning now.  Explore your options for repair or replacement so you already have answers when it fails and you're under pressure.  Try to sock away whatever money you can spare a little at a time between now and when it fails.  If it survives for awhile and you can accumulate a small nest egg, eventually dealing with it won'tbe as bad of a financial burden.